# JavaScript forEach() debug: code review?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, console.log

My output needs to be:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 
09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
```

I'm a bit out of practice and am having trouble getting started. I'll walk you through my thought process so far, but if you could give me a push in the right direction it would be amazing!

**First**, I think I need to set up cell-object model, like this;

```
var mod = {val: 0, first: 0, second: 0};
```

**Second**, I need to create an array of 32 of these objects.

```
var arr = [];
var i = 1;
function createArray(){
  while (i < 33) {
      if (i<10){
          mod = { 
                  val: i, 
                  first: 0, 
                  second: i 
                }
      } else {
          mod = { 
                  val: i, 
                  first: i.toString().split('').reverse().pop(), 
                  second: i.toString().split('').pop()
                }
          arr.push(mod);
      }
      i++;
  }
};
createArray();

var result = '';
arr.forEach(function(space){
  space = space.first.toString() + space.second.toString();
  if(result.length < 24){
    result += space + ' ';
  } else {
    console.log(result);
    result = '';
  }
});
```

This produces, to me, a strange outcome:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

What's going on here? It's skipping out on `09` and `18`, but why? I just can't see it.

**EDIT**

As **@zerkms** pointed out, there was a mistake in my inputting into SO. `i++` is supposed to be inside the while loop; otherwise it produces an infinite loop.

Comment: The code you pasted has an infinite loop.

Comment: When the line reaches the length of 24 - you lose a value, since you don't save it anywhere.

Comment: the code doesn't have an infinite loop when i run it so let me double check

Comment: @zerkms, no...just no.

Comment: Well, it does have `while (i < 33) {` does not change `i` in its body.

Comment: yes as @zerkms said -- I think it's a mistake in copying into stackoverflow. i++; should be inside the while

Comment: Btw, if you're curious that's how it could be done "properly" http://jsfiddle.net/x848nq13/ (I mean in more readable and maintainable fashion)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. This was my first go-through so I definitely appreciate learning how to make things more efficient and readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't include the last value when on the end of the line.

```
  result += space + ' ';  // always do this
  if(result.length > 24) {
    console.log(result);
    result = '';
  }
```

Comment: Yes, just did! Thank you. Seems I'm still figuring out the order of things.

Comment: My interpretation of your answer:  `result` needs to be changed before it's checked by the conditional, otherwise, it gets lost like @zerkms said earlier.

Comment: Yes. It gets 'lost' because it's just not executed -- only the 'else' branch is. The else branch resets 'result' and the value of space is ignored.

Comment: In terms of a 'review', try and see if you can write the code *without* changing a variable (here 'space') or using forEach. One way is to use "map" then "join".

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful for me. I'll give it a try.